# ls doesn't list my files in the right order

Tags: bash, sorting, ls

When I type `ls` in bash, it should retrieve the names of files and directories in alphabetical order by default.

Unfortunately, I get the following result:

```
--  ---  00  -01  01  -02
```

The result I was expecting is:

```
--  ---  -01  -02  00  01
```

The `-` character(s) in the filenames are preventing the default sort from working correctly. I need the file names to be sorted using the same method as php `strcmp`.

Why does the `-` character cause a problem with sorting? Are there any other characters that will cause an issue? What's the best way in bash to accurately sort filenames?

**Edit**

The `ls` command was returning the same incorrect results on my home computer with `Manjaro` and my backup server using the `ltfp` command.

Using `LC_ALL=C ls -1` as [paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) suggested in his answer, works when testing on Majaro, but no luck getting it to work when using `lftp`:

```
echo $(lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate no; cd "$1"; LC_ALL=C ls" -u $username,$password $server)
```

**Edit - Solved**

In `lftp`, `cls -l` gets the correct order and with the full details that I need.

```
echo $(lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate no; cd "$1"; cls -l" -u $username,$password $server)
```

Comment: I get the correct output (`-- --- -01 -02 00 01`) with `ls` or `echo *`.  What system are you on?  Even `LC_ALL= ls` gives me the same output, on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: @codeforester, that's *possibly* becaue your default locale is `C`, or another locale that sorts in the expected manner.

Comment: I am using 'Manjaro' on my home computer, however, I am performing the `ls` command on my backup server using `lftp`. `LC_ALL=C ls -1` works with Majaro but not my backup server with `lftp`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: `locale | grep LC_ALL` gives me `LC_ALL=`.

Comment: @codeforester, what are the *other* values from your `locale`. My `LC_ALL` is also blank but I suspect it reverts to one of the more specific cases in that point (most likely `LANG`). My guess would be that `LC_ALL` overrides all the others *if it's actually set* to something.

Comment: @paxdiablo: here is the full output of `locale`: `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: When I `lftp` into my backup server, both `locale` and `LC_ALL=C` give a `Command not found` error. `cls -1` gives the correct order but does not give other information I needs, such as file size. Making it work in `lftp` is probably beyond the scope of my original question. I'll just fix the order with `php`.

Comment: @DanBray A brief glance at the man page of lftp says "lftp  has  shell-like  command  syntax", so I guess by *shell-like* it doesn't actually give you a full shell, so it doesn't support the LC_ALL=C syntax. You probably have to look into other ways of setting environment variables.

Comment: BTW, what's up with the `echo $(lftp ...)` syntax, as opposed to just running `lftp`? That's going to have some very unfortunate side effects -- for example, if someone created a local file named `* READ ME FIRST * .txt`, then the `*`s will be replaced with local filenames.

Comment: Please use the "Add an Answer" button to add your own answers, instead of editing them into the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I use echo so that my `bash script` returns the results to my `php` code. If I remove `echo`, I don't get any results.

Comment: That's hard to believe. `echo "$(something)"` runs `something`, captures everything it wrote to stdout, and then passes that string to `echo`. `echo $(something)` without the quotes does the same thing but with far more bugs (such as the one I mentioned above). Thing is, just `something` alone runs `something` and lets it write to stdout, so the `echo` and the `$( )` syntax are both utterly unnecessary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't want to do that because making it work in `lftp` was beyond the scope of my original question and I marked @paxdiablo as being the solution.

Comment: You can add *an* answer without marking it accepted. Whereas if it's not pertinent, why mention it at all?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Even this doesn't work `results=$(lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-force true; set ssl:verify-certificate no; cd $dir; cls -l" -u $username,$password $server)
echo "$results"` but if I remove the quotes around `echo "$results"` it works.

Comment: @DanBray, that implies your PHP code is *expecting* results to be placed on a single line. That's dangerous -- how would a filename with spaces be read? The right thing to do here is to fix the PHP code to expect content in the same format `lftp` writes it in, with newlines -- not spaces -- between items.

Comment: ...on a related note, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Recently seen on SuperUser: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)` or ```echo `stuff` ```?](https://superuser.com/questions/1352850/what-is-wrong-with-echo-stuff-or-echo-stuff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the default sorting specified by your locale. You can *find out* what locale it will use with the command ... hmm let me think, ... yes, that's it, `locale` :-)

```
pax$ locale
LANG=en_AU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_AU:en
LC_CTYPE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_AU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

If you set the locale to something more *sensible* <sup>(a)</sup>, you'll see it acts as desired:

```
pax$ ls
--  ---  00  01  -01  -02
pax$ LANG=C ls
--  ---  -01  -02  00  01
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Defined, in the context of this question, as `C`.

Comment: Using `LC_ALL=C ls -1` works when testing with Majaro but when I use with the `lftp` command on my backup server I get either the same wrong results or no results.

Comment: @DanBray, right -- the FTP protocol doesn't let you run shell commands (`ls` in `lftp` is not actually invoking `/bin/ls`), so you can't set environment variables. Well, generally -- `lftp` has a whole lot of backend protocols it supports, and how each of them works can vary.

Comment: @Dan, support for locales is baked into whatever program you're trying to use. It may well be that `lftp` doesn't know or care about the locale. If that's the case, you can probably build up the command staring in a sorted manner outside of `lftp` and then pass in the correct string. In other words, call `lftp` to get the files into a list, sort that list with `bash/sort`, then pass the command with the sported list back to `lftp`.